# Elastic Search: ngram filter with aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to surpass the nGram filter when doing an aggregation?

i have a defined ngram filter with :

```
 "ngram_filter": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "100"
        }
```

and i want to a an aggregation on a field with this filter defined on it:

i get the buckets result filtered:

```
   "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "_",
          "doc_count": 394
        },
        {
          "key": "a",
          "doc_count": 365
        },
        {
          "key": "m",
          "doc_count": 357
        },
        {
          "key": "i",
          "doc_count": 344
        },
        {
          "key": "_d",
          "doc_count": 341
        },
        {
          "key": "d",
          "doc_count": 341
        },
        {
          "key": "e",
          "doc_count": 319
        },
        {
          "key": "r",
          "doc_count": 289
        },
        {
          "key": "l",
          "doc_count": 260
        },
        {
          "key": "l_",
          "doc_count": 221
        }
    ]
```

also i do not want to change the ngram analyzer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that field you have the custom nGram analyzer set for, you need to add a sub-field that should keep the "original" terms (using `standard` analyzer or the field should be `not_analyzed`) or the terms that you want in your aggregation. Then your aggregation should point to your `field.sub_field` field.

Ok, try this sub-optimal solution (due to how fast this is compared to the sub-field approach), without changing the mapping:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "whatever": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "_source['yourFieldName']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i cannot change the ngram analyzer nor the mappings for the field... i need a way to build the es query in order to have the aggregation surpass the analyzer.... thank you

Comment: Updated my answer with a sub-optimal solution.

Comment: thx... script solution will make it easier to strengthen a point in changing the mappings :)